# Play audio stream using WebAudio API

Tags: webkit, audio-streaming, webrtc

I have a client/server audio synthesizer where the server (java) dynamically generates an audio stream (Ogg/Vorbis) to be rendered by the client using an HTML5 audio element.  Users can tweak various parameters and the server immediately alters the output accordingly.  Unfortunately the audio element buffers (prefetches) very aggressively so changes made by the user won't be heard until minutes later, literally.

Trying to disable preload has no effect, and apparently this setting is only 'advisory' so there's no guarantee that it's behavior would be consistent across browsers.

I've been reading everything that I can find on WebRTC and the evolving WebAudio API and it seems like all of the pieces I need are there but I don't know if it's possible to connect them up the way I'd like to.

I looked at RTCPeerConnection, it does provide low latency but it brings in a lot of baggage that I don't want or need (STUN, ICE, offer/answer, etc) and currently it seems to only support a limited set of codecs, mostly geared towards voice.  Also since the server side is in java I think I'd have to do a lot of work to teach it to 'speak' the various protocols and formats involved.

AudioContext.decodeAudioData works great for a static sample, but not for a stream since it doesn't process the incoming data until it's consumed the entire stream.

What I want is the exact functionality of the audio tag (i.e. HTMLAudioElement) without any buffering.  If I could somehow create a MediaStream object that uses the server URL for its input then I could create a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode and send that output to context.destination.  This is not very different than what AudioContext.decodeAudioData already does, except that method creates a static buffer, not a stream.

I would like to keep the Ogg/Vorbis compression and eventually use other codecs, but one thing that I may try next is to send raw PCM and build audio buffers on the fly, just as if they were being generated programatically by javascript code.  But again, I think all of the parts already exist, and if there's any way to leverage that I would be most thrilled to know about it!

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting on ?  Did you resolve this question ?  I am solving a similar challenge.  On the browser side I'm using web audio API which has nice ways to render streaming input audio data, and nodejs on the server side using web sockets as the middleware to send the browser streaming PCM buffers.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just noticed your comment.  I ended up implementing something that sounds pretty similar to what you described.  I open a web socket connection for streaming record data from the browser to the server and for streaming data back from the server to the browser.